# Db2 stored procedure to insert

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I'm new to db2 and stored procedure i created a stored procedure to insert records into a database but the stored procedure doesn't work, the code is as follows:

```
drop procedure product_create ;                                                                                

CREATE PROCEDURE product_Create(                                                                               
out errmsg       char(256),                                                                                    
in  inCucode       char(6),                                                                                      
in  inProdCode     char(25),                                                                                     
in  inDescription  char(80),                                                                                     
in  inUPC          char(25),                                                                                     
in  inuom          char(3),                                                                                      
in  instdpack      decimal(5,0),                                                                                 
in  inweight       decimal(9,4),                                                                                 
in  inlength       decimal(9,4),                                                                                 
in  inwidth        decimal(9,4),                                                                                 
in  inheight       decimal(9,4)                                                                                 

) 
language sql

BEGIN   

if          errmsg = ' '     
insert      INTO prmast
            ( prcucd,
              prprcd,
              prdes1,
              prupc#,
              prworu,
              prwuts,
              prntwt,
              prlong,
              prwide,
              prhigh
            )

values      ( inCucode,
              inProdCode,
              inDescription,
              inUPC,
              inuom,
              instdpack,
              inweight,
              inlength,
              inwidth,
              inheight,
        ) ;
end if ;
return ;
end
```

Is this the correct structure for an insert query in stored procedure am i forgetting anything, your help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the error you get, also why are you checking of `errmsg = ' '` before doing the `INSERT`.. what is your table structure look like?

Comment: it's not inserting in the database, `errmsg = '  ' ` is if db2 returns not errmsg then insert the records in the database

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your issue as following:

1. Create a table "prmast":

`CREATE TABLE prmast(prcucd char(6), prprcd char(25), prdes1 char(80), prupc# char(25), prworu char(3), prwuts dec(5,0), prntwt dec(9,4), prlong dec(9,4), prwide dec(9,4), prhigh dec(9,4));`

2. Write the stored procedure and save it to a file called `sol.txt`

   `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE product_Create(

   out errmsg       char(5),

   in  inCucode       char(6),

   in  inProdCode     char(25),

   in  inDescription  char(80),

   in  inUPC          char(25),

   in  inuom          char(3),

   in  instdpack      decimal(5,0),

   in  inweight       decimal(9,4),

   in  inlength       decimal(9,4),

   in  inwidth        decimal(9,4),

   in  inheight       decimal(9,4)

   ) 
   language sql
   BEGIN

   DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5);
   Insert INTO prmast
           ( prcucd,
             prprcd,
             prdes1,
             prupc#,
             prworu,
             prwuts,
             prntwt,
             prlong,
             prwide,
             prhigh
           )values

           ( inCucode,
             inProdCode,
             inDescription,
             inUPC,
             inuom,
             instdpack,
             inweight,
             inlength,
             inwidth,
             inheight
           ) ;
   SET errmsg = SQLSTATE;
   end@`
3. run the procedure: `db2 -td@ -vf sol.txt`
4. Then, I call the procedure:

   `db2 "call product_Create(?, 'a','b','c','d','e',6,7,8,9,10)"`

   Value of output parameters

   ---

   Parameter Name  : ERRMSG
   Parameter Value : 00000

   Return Status = 0`
5. Verify it works:

`db2 select * from prmast

PRCUCD PRPRCD                    PRDES1                                                                           PRUPC#                    PRWORU PRWUTS  PRNTWT      PRLONG      PRWIDE      PRHIGH

### ------ ------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------- ------ ------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------

a      b                         c                                                                                d                         e           6.      7.0000      8.0000      9.0000     10.00
00

1 record(s) selected.`

There are several points to be noticed for your procedure:

- You can use `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` to define your procedure. It will drop existing procedure definition and replace it with the definition you just run. In other words, you don't have to explicitly `DROP PROCEDURE`
- `char(255)` is out of range. declare output "errmsg" as `char(5)` should be good enough.
- You can use `SET` statement to explicitly check if your SQL statement executed successfully or not.
- The `@` symbol at the end of procedure indicates db2 that to not use `;` as end of statement because you use `;` as end of statement of a SQL, which belongs to part of stored procedure definition. That is also why you want to use `-td@` option when you execute your clp. That tells DB2 to use `@` instead of `;` as end-of-statement symbol.
- Also, there is `,` right after column "inheight", which is the last column and should not have `,` following
- When calling stored procedure, `?` is required as placeholder for "OUT" parameter.

One more note, if you want to insert values from the selection result of another table, you may want to use "cursor" instead of explicitly supplying the values to your stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry that helped alot

Comment: @JohnPublic Glad to help. Could you accept this answer? Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting this error: 42704 and PRMAST in *liblfile not found SQLCODE = -204 i google it but not sure to to resolve it @Jerry

Comment: @JohnPublic SQLCODE=-204 means "Object not defined to DB2". Have you created PRMAST table? What is *liblfile?  You can find SQL code error message meaning here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DB2_SQL_return_codes